# Can i store files and boot from the same External hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot, files, external-hdd, sata

is it possible to run Ubuntu from an external hard drive and store files(music, movies, games) in that very same external hard drive? BTW the external hard drive i have is basically a 2.5" 200GB laptop HDD with a USB 2.0 SATA enclosure.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to askubuntu!

The answer is affirmative. I myself am running Ubuntu from an external hard drive with a separate partition (FAT32 formatted) where I keep my music and common documents.

The only caveat is making sure that in the installation process you select the right drive (the external one) as the boot loader target. You will have to manually edit your partitions and leave free space for your extra partition(s).

You should also make sure (!) you are editing the partitions on your external hard drive. Remember that formatting the disk will erase its contents, it would be unfortunate if you end up erasing your internal hard drive :)

This image shows the point at which you must choose the right drive for the bootloader (this is also an image of the **Do something else...** installation option):

[image]

---

My recommendation (a simplistic one) is to create the following partitions:

```
/boot   with ~300 MB
swap    depends on the RAM of your system (if you've got 1 GB of RAM try with ~2 GB of swap)
/       with ~25 GB (if installing a lot of software consider ~35 GB)
/home   make the sum of this and the others equal to ~100 GB
```

then leave the remaining `100 GB` for common storage (format it to FAT32, for example).